# Stack Exchange sites: connection is not private in Chrome Browser

Tags: bug, ssl, google-chrome

After installing the Windows OS and the latest version of Google Chrome yesterday, and even after enabling the [HTTPS Everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS_Everywhere) addon, I'm getting *"Your connection is not private"*.

But in Firefox it is working correctly.

[image]

```
Google Chrome    81.0.4044.129 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
Revision    3d71af9f5704a40b85806f4d08925db24605ba25-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#979}
OS    Windows 10 OS Version 1903 (Build 18362.113)
JavaScript    V8 8.1.307.31
Flash    32.0.0.363 C:\Users\nishanth\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\PepperFlash\32.0.0.363\pepflashplayer.dll
User Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36
Command Line    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --enable-audio-service-sandbox
Executable Path    C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Comment: No repro on Chrome 81 Win 10. Probably something to do with your network. What type of connection are you on?

Comment: BSNL 3G connected via USB Adapter. Issue appeared after Reinstalling windows 10 and chrome changed 32 bit to 64 bit after downloading standalone installer from official website. still same @SamuelLiew

Comment: What does the certificate looks like?

Comment: This CA Root certificate is not trusted because it is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store. The certificate cannot be verified up to a trusted certification authority @rene

Comment: Gives such error in all sites that had installed Let's Encrypt certificate from Google Chrome only @rene

Comment: Are you on a corporate, domain joined computer? Is it possible that a sysadmin removed  the Let's Encrypt CA cert? What happens if you visit https://socvr.org/ ? That site also has a Let's Encrypt SSL cert.

Comment: Same warning message in Chrome. But not in FireFox @rene

Comment: Mine is a domain joined computer and not connected to Domain. ISP is different @rene

Comment: Your windows certificate store is borked. Firefox uses their own certificate store so that explains the difference, This is not a problem SE can or should fix. The problem is on your end.

Comment: How to get around this problem temporarily or permanently @rene

Comment: Use firefox or ask the sysadmin that removed the root CA's to restore those. Or see if you are allowed to import Root CA's yourself. The Chain of Trust for Let's Encrypt is here: https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213225/discussion-between-ns--and-rene).

Comment: Recently I began seeing the same message in Chrome and Edge.